# Thread delays during termination

Tags: java, multithreading

```
//Main.java
public static boolean isEnd() {
    return end;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    execProductNumber.execute(new ProductNumber(allBuffer));

    end = true;
    System.out.println("Leaving main");
    //execProductNumber.shutdown();
}

//ProductNumber.java
public void run() {
    while(!Main.isEnd()) {
        //something
    }
    System.out.println("Leaving thread");
}
```

I am starting my program, gets output:

```
Leaving main
Leaving thread
```

and program does not terminate immediately (I need to wait about 1,5 min to successful end of program). When I tried to stop thread by shutdown() (comment) it stopped right after. While trying to debug it I found that it delays on that(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):

```
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
        Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
        Runnable task = w.firstTask;
        w.firstTask = null;
        w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
        boolean completedAbruptly = true;
        try {
            while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) { //here
                w.lock();
                // If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
                // if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
                // requires a recheck in second case to deal with
                // shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
```

Waits there some time and then moves on. Why? What happens there? Is that necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `execProductNumber` is an `ExecutorService`, then you need to call `shutdown()` immediately after the last job is submitted to the service.  This *will* allow any already submitted jobs to finish.

> and program does not terminate immediately

Right.  It is reaching the end of `main()` but the thread associated with the `ExecutorService` is non-daemon and it is still running.  By calling `execProductNumber.shutdown();`, your application will finish immediately after the `ProductNumber` task completes.

> While trying to debug it I found that it delays on that(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):

Right, the worker threads are waiting patiently for another task to be submitted to the thread-pool.